# Unable to install any python packages using pip on windows

Tags: python, windows, pip

I'm relatively new to python and pip tool.I'm trying install python bindings of selenium in my windows system using pip but I'm getting an error message saying that "  **Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement selenium (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for selenium**"

Can someone please help me out?

I'm using Python 2.7 and I don't have any other version installed along with it in my system.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPvDT.png)

Comment: I have same problem, I found a solution in this link: https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/41253 but it is for other OS except windows.